# How to drag a div out of a overflow-y:auto div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, drag

I am working on a project that has a drag and drop function. The drag option is a bit long and therefore scrolling is necessary.

This is the JS fiddle of my testing script: http://jsfiddle.net/2e9Jd/30/

As you can see, I am unable to drag the elements out of the div after setting `overflow-y:auto` even I set `overflow-x:visible`. It seems that when I set `overflow-y:auto`, `overflow-x` is forced to be auto. Is it a bug on CSS? Any work around?

Comment: Is your fiddle updated? I don't see any `div` with `overflow-y` or `overflow-x` setting.

Comment: Also, are you trying to drag the div that contains the text "drag me" out of `#element`? It seems that you have made `#element` (the yellow box) the drag element.

Comment: @light Sorry, I have forgoten to press the update button. You should be able to see the correct code now.